# Python: how to append user input elements to an empty list

Tags: python, list, input

I'm trying to create a list of size *n* whose elements are names - both are user inputs. Here is the following code:

```
names = []
for _ in range(int(input("Number of names to query (n): "))):
    names = names.append(input("Enter the names to query: "))
```

I get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
I don't understand what this means and why this is happening. *names* seems to be a list object?

```
print(type(names))
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: `names` modifies the list, it doesn't return the modified list.

Comment: The return value of `names.append` is `None`, so when you reassign that to `names` you have lost your list. Don't reassign the variable `names`; `list.append` modifies in-place.

Answer (score 0):

.append will edit the existing list. You don't need to assign it to a variable.

These types of methods in python often return None. So you are setting names to None and then trying to call .append on it again.